# Generate an Skype shareable conversation link

Tags: api, rest, skype

For a year now Skype has had the ability to create shareable conversation links under the domain join.skype.com that allow to start a group conversation without even needing an Skype account. You can generate them through the Skype client using the "New" button.

However I can't find anywhere any documentation on how to create those type of links programmatically. I guess it's just a matter of calling an URL or a simple REST API, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Any clues or indications?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn745882.aspx#sectionSection0

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I'm looking for. I've already located that page, but it is aimed at creating URIs to connect to existing Skype accounts using "skype:" URIs. What I'm talking about is the new feature introduced 1 year ago to create links, independent of any user, that anyone can use to join a conversation even without an Skype account. Thanks.

Comment: No answer, but a corresponding [forum entry](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_web-skype_callms-skype_audioms/generate-joinskypecom-link-from-external/a6902893-b670-4f1a-a461-8836deb0bee4?tm=1511772719463)